# Find Sting in line of text document

Tags: java

I am trying to find the string `all` in this simple but I am getting the output `ho hum, i found it on line 0` How can I fix that?

I appreciate any help.

**Simple:**

```
apple 05:09 05:39 06:11 06:41 07:11 07:41 08:11 all 17:11 17:41 18:11 18:41 19:11 19:41
chair 05:11 05:41 06:14 06:44 07:14 07:44 08:14 30 17:14 17:44 18:14 18:44 19:14 19:44
table 05:13 05:43 06:17 06:47 07:17 07:47 08:17 Min 17:17 17:47 18:17 18:47 19:17 19:47
```

**Code:**

```
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path + File.separator
                + newName);

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
            int lineNum = 0;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                if(line.contains("all")){
                    System.out.println("ho hum, i found it on line " +lineNum);

                }
}
```

Comment: increment `lineNum`...

Comment: its on lineNum 0 in this case. However you need to increment the value of lineNum in the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "lineNum++;" after the start of your while loop but before your if statement (unless you want the first line to be line 0, in which case increment after the if). You are never incrementing lineNum so it will stay 0.

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            lineNum++;
            if(line.contains("all")){
                System.out.println("ho hum, i found it on line " +lineNum);

            }
```